# How to remove all php function contents if return false?

Tags: php, html

hey guys i have function in php and i am trying to find a way to remove all function contents if the result is empty or false
here is an example:

```
function myfunction($result){
?>
 <div><a>Hello</a></div>
<?php
   if(empty($result)) {
      return false;
   }
}
```

my problem is when the return is false, the function output is

> Hello

and i want to remove it if return is false.

Answer (score 4):

You have to return false before outputting anything

```
function myfunction($result){
    if(empty($result)) {
        return false;
    }
    ?>
    <div><a>Hello</a></div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: thank you sir it works when i open a page, but when I use this function somewhere and get the result by ajax, its doesn't remove the output

Comment: @kovritaisThelife - This function will return `false` every single time, no matter where you call it from, as long as `$result` is considered empty (example: `null`, empty string, `false`, `0`). if it doesn't return false but rather output the "hello" message, then you're not passing in an empty value.

Comment: `<div><a>Hello</a></div>` will be always thrown in the output regardless of the PHP execution flow.

Comment: @nice_dev - Not if `$result` is evaluated as empty.

Comment: @M.Eriksson I haven't tested this yet but OP seems to have the same issue still.

Comment: @nice_dev - I think that has more to do with how the OP is using the function and what they pass as an argument. This answer does indeed answer/solve the question they've posted. Here's a demo: https://3v4l.org/nNBKN

Comment: @M.Eriksson Makes sense. I would say it is still unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function myfunction($result){
  if(empty($result)) {
      return '<div></div>';
   }else{
       return "<div><a>Hello</a></div>";
   }
}
echo myfunction($result);
```

Comment: This looks fine but OP wishes to return it instead of echoing it(which is like hard coupling)

Answer (score 0):

You can return empty/false response when it is empty and return the HTML when it is not, like below:

```
<?php

function myfunction($result){
  return empty($result) ? false : "<div><a>Hello</a></div>";
}
```